# Have another way to gettext from table in html and That table has nested table

Tags: dom, jsoup

how can I get elements from all table and each table don't select nested table  I want to select table from id= customers,customers2,customers3 but the problem is customers3 is nested in customers2  I don't want to use get by id and customers2 don't have any customers3 item  please help and thank you

PS. for easiest way you can try in web https://try.jsoup.org/ 
Example file:
https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/files/403482/Table01.txt
PS. jhy lead me to ask here

Comment: Do you want to get the `tr` of each table including the nested one?

Comment: Mainly I tried to convert HTMLtable to array
but the result its

customers,
customers2{customers3}
(got 2 Table)

what i want need to be
customers,
customers2,
customers3
(got 3 table and second table don't get customer3 as nested table)

Answer (score 0):

After I spend a lot of time I find the way to get but it its work for 1 nested table only and code looks dirty (I have tested with this file https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/files/403482/Table01.txt)

```
StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
                FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\html\\"+"Table01.html"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            contentBuilder.append(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
String html = contentBuilder.toString();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
// Take nested table as Elements first
Elements nestedTables = doc.select("td table");
// remove nested Table in document
doc.select("td table").remove();
// Then get it again
Elements tables = doc.select("table");
```

this is  as best as I can.
Thank you very much, Davide Pastore
sorry for the lack in English

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a page with tables like this:

```
<table id="customers">
    <tr>
        <td>foo1</td>
        <td>bar1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="customers2">
    <tr>
        <td>foo2</td>
        <td>bar2</td>
        <td>
            <table id="customers3">
                <tr>
                    <td>foo3</td>
                    <td>bar3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And you want to get the elements, excluding embedded elements.

You can use CSS Selectors to accomplish this.

```
for (Element cell : doc.select("table td:not(:has(table))"))
    System.out.println(e.ownText());
```

**Output**

```
foo1
bar1
foo2
bar2
foo3
bar3
```

---

Also, you don't need to open a file with a buffer and grab all of the text content for jsoup.  You can simply pass a file to Jsoup.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("test.html"), "UTF-8");
```

See the [Jsoup Cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file) for more examples.